Alert not shown because 'Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed'
I implemented async/ await and Result. An error thrown in my data adapter (DA) is routed properly into my domain store (DoS) and handled there in the Result .failure case as shown below.
But I struggle to display the error as an alert. Getting the following message.
Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.
My domain store looks like this:
@MainActor
class TaskDoS: ObservableObject{
    @Published var tasks: [TaskModel] = []
    @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
    @Published var showingError = false
    
    var dataDS: TaskDS
    
    init(dataDS: ITaskDataService) {
        self.dataDS = TaskDS(dataDA: dataDS)
    }
    
    //loader for tasks.
    func loadTasks() async {
        let result = await dataDS.readTasks()
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let tasks):
            self.tasks = tasks
        case .failure(let error):
            
            //I tried to run this code inside a DispatchQueue.main.async closure but without effects.
            self.errorMessage = error.guidance
            self.showingError.toggle()
            
            DebugPrint.value(error, prompt: "TaskDoS:loadTask:")
        }
    }
}

The corresponding screen looks like this:
struct TaskListScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var taskDoS: TaskDoS
    @State private var editTask: String = "" //mock type.
    
    var selectedCatalogue: String = "mockTaskCopy" //mockTaskPaste.
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(taskDoS.tasks) { task in
                    Text(selectedCatalogue == "mockTaskCopy" ? "copy task\(task)" : "paste task\(task)")
                }
            }
            .task {
                await taskDoS.loadTasks()
            }
            //this alert can't be shown.
            .alert("Error", isPresented: $taskDoS.showingError) {
            } message: {
                Text(taskDoS.errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the full sample project.
//
//  MVConcurrentDataFlow.swift
//
//  Created by Mat Fetsch on 2024-07-08.
//
// this sample app uses a DataAdapter to read and create items.
// the DataAdapter conforms to IDataService protocol and the DataService makes the data available for the app.
// the DomainService consumes data conforming to IDataService protocol and is the ObervableObject to the screens/ views.
// the main screen/ view injects the dependencies into an EnvironmentObject.

import SwiftUI

//Data
struct Item: Hashable {
    var name: String
}

struct MockDb {
    private var items: [Item] = []
    
    func readItems() async throws -> [Item] {
        throw AdapterError.dataError //testing the error handling.
        
        [Item(name: "Peter"), Item(name: "Joan")]
    }
    mutating func createItem(_ item: Item) async throws -> Bool {
        items.append(item)
        return true
    }
}

enum AdapterError: Error {
    case dataError
}

struct ItemDataAdapter: IDataService {
    var mock: MockDb
    
    func read() async -> Result<[Item], AdapterError> {
        do {
            let result = try await mock.readItems()
            return .success(result)
        } catch {
            return .failure(AdapterError.dataError)
        }
    }
    mutating func create(_ item: Item) async -> Result<Bool, AdapterError> {
        do {
            let result = try await mock.createItem(item)
            return .success(result)
        } catch {
            return .failure(AdapterError.dataError)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemDataService: IDataService {
    var dataAdapter: IDataService
    
    func read() async -> Result<[Item], AdapterError> {
        await dataAdapter.read()
    }
    mutating func create(_ item: Item) async -> Result<Bool, AdapterError> {
        await dataAdapter.create(item)
    }
}

protocol IDataService {
    func read() async -> Result<[Item], AdapterError>
    mutating func create(_ item: Item) async -> Result<Bool, AdapterError>
}

//Domain
@MainActor
class ItemDomainStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    
    var dataService: ItemDataService
    
    init(dataService: IDataService) {
        self.dataService = ItemDataService(dataAdapter: dataService)
        
        Task {
            await read()
        }
    }
    
    func read() async {
        let result = await dataService.read()
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let items):
            self.items = items
        case .failure(let error):
            items = []
            
            //thrown error from mockDb is shown here.
            //how can I show the error as an alert to the user?
            print(error)
        }
    }
    func create(_ item: Item) async {
        //debugger message: Cannot call mutating async function 'create' on actor-isolated property 'dataService'
        //how can I call create?
        //let result = await dataService.create(item)
    }
}

//Presentation
struct ItemListScreen: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var domainStore: ItemDomainStore
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(domainStore.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            Button("create item") {
                Task {
                    await domainStore.create(Item(name: "Marry"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//main screen.
struct MVConcurrentDataFlow: View {
    let mock = MockDb()
    
    var body: some View {
        ItemListScreen()
            .environmentObject(ItemDomainStore(dataService: ItemDataService(dataAdapter: ItemDataAdapter(mock: mock))))
    }
}

#Preview {
    MVConcurrentDataFlow()
}



I wasn't able to copy-paste your code to test it. So can you try to create EmptyView() inside the NavigationStack and assign the .task() to it?

FIX: EmptyView() doesn't work. Color.clear.frame(width: 0, height: 0) works. Sorry for writing it wrong.

Hi. I added the colored frame but the debugging message and the behaviour stays the same.

Where does the error appear?

In the OververableObject at @Published var tasks: [TaskModel] = [].

It might be related to using the '@Environment' to inject the domain store (like a view model class), when binding ‘@Published' properties. It’s not there when I use ‘@StateObject’, what I tested with a small sample program, but then I’ve to create an instance of the domain store in the View itself, what I wouldn’t like to do.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Uually the async func isn't declared inside the object because then it would be trying to use self which could lead to issues. You really need the async func to take params and return results, e.g.
func loadItems() async throws -> [Item] {

Then you can do:
.task {
    do {
        let items = await itemService.loadItems()
        self.result = .success(items)
    }
    catch {
        self.result = .failed(error)
    }
}

Usually the async func is in an EnvironmentKey struct so it can be mocked for previews, e.g.
@Environment(\.itemService) var itemService

Note I renamed your Task to Item because that would conflict with the async Task.

Thanks malhal. Maybe you can take a look. I Added the full sample project code because I really can’t figure out how to show the alert. And I figured out another problem with calling a mutating function in this scenario - but that may be discussed in a separate thread.

The problem was solved here link
